# Linking to malicious sites

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

In [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33664/what-does-this-injected-code-do/33665#33665) question I've found a number of sites with similar code (presumably part of the same attack), I'd like to include links as reference (or blocks of code failing that) but I'm wondering what the policy is regarding linking directly to (obvious) drive-by-download sites and the like.

Edit: 
It looks like the code included in [this question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1242/question-being-flagged-by-antivirus) is causing some AV's to flag the page as malicious. As a result, it doesn't look like we should be including directly malicious code in the page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it is okay to reference such sites, but please make the links non-clickable and include a warning.

Posting the relevant code is preferable.