# Question being flagged by Antivirus

Tags: support

[This thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33664/what-does-this-injected-code-do) is being flagged and blocked by Avast and Kaspersky antivirus products. Avast flagged it as `Threat:JS:Decode-XA[Trj]`. Could someone look into this and get it cleaned up before Sec.SE ends up on a search engine's blacklist or something?

(Thanks to @TRiG for pointing this out [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9121421#9121421).)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that the pattern matching to identify threats doesn't consider whether or not they're actually labelled in such a way to be executed by the browser. I'm not quite sure what to do about that since it's correctly identifying the example as Bad Stuff, but the example is also presented in an innocuous way that isn't being executed by those visiting the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i added that observation to the edit i made recently. Should i perhaps create a link to pastebins?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me.